# android send sms to android programatically

Tags: android

i have a server which needs to authenticate any android client, this server will send an sms to each client. is there any possible solution to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the Google services for Cloud Messaging.  That sounds like it will do what you need
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: i want to send sms from server to android, the message service should receive it not my application , u got me?

Comment: that's why your question was closed - you're asking for someone to write you a generic server message app.